# How to force 0% code coverage on untested files in custom SonarQube plugin?

Tags: plugins, sonarqube

I'm trying to develop a SonarQube plugin. My current problem is the code coverage. As many other language plugins I have to parse a XML-Report that only contains coverage information about files that got touched by a test, so the coverage is way to high as all the untouched files are missing.

I now tried to force 0% coverage for those untested files with the following code:

```
for (String token : line.split(" ")) {
    if (ArrayUtils.contains(CONDITION_KEYWORDS, token)) {
        keywords++;
    }
}
coverageMeasuresBuilder.setHits(lineNumber, 0);
if (keywords > 0) {
    coverageMeasuresBuilder.setConditions(lineNumber, (int) Math.pow(2, keywords), 0);
}
```

This code gets executed for each line and after all lines the measures gets saved. This works as expected (the coverage is now more correct), but on the SonarQube web interface something strange happens: if I use the above code and click on "Unit test coverage" only the files with forced 0% coverage are shown and the files with real coverage information are no longer listed. If I do not use this code, I can only see the files touched by a test.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We used the plug-in in our prod-system as we had no other choise. Yesterday some developer requested some excludes and suddenly all packages were displayed. I guess that SonarQube has a limitation of packages that it can display in the coverage view.